# How to use the isEnabled method to disable child ListView items in android

Tags: android, listview

Well I want to disable some listview items. I understand I can override them in adapter. But I dont understand the part

// return false if position == position you want to disable

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // return false if position == position you want to disable
}
```

Shall you mean I put it onCreate 
with something like

```
if(adapter.isEnabled(0))
{
    adapter.isEnabled(0) == false;
}
```

is it true by default?

I am a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

ListView needs a data sources , you'd better do something with the data sources than do it on listView .

```
    for example :
    public class DataSources{
       private boolean isEnable = false;
       private Other other = ....;
       .....
       getter and setter

      }

    public class Som....{

    listView.setAdapter(new XXAdapter(dataSources){
      //something in your adapter
      if(dataSources.getIsEnable){
         //then  xxx .setOnClickListener..
      }

    }
    }
```